# Recognize only one monitor until login

Tags: 16.04, monitor, desktop-background

I have the following problem: 
I have 2 monitors connected to my gpu, one samsung 24' and one hp 17', when I power on my pc, i only get the background partially on the big screen, and black the rest of the background, i think this is because ubuntu recognizes first the little monitor, since the background on the little one is okay and in the big monitor i get only background for the size of the little monitor. 
I want to know how can I make ubuntu to recognize the samsung 24' as the first monitor, and then when i'm logged recognize the little monitor so i don't have this issue.

running ubuntu 16.04 btw